# Custom layer legend properties don't show up on QGIS Server

Tags: pyqgis, legend, qgis-server

In QGIS there is no UI option to remove Band name from raster layer legends and invert their order. That's why a made a PyQGIS script to do that from Python console. This works great and shows up in QGIS:

```py
model = QgsLayerTreeModel(QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot())
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
ids = root.findLayerIds()

for id in ids:
    if id.startswith("my_raster_layer"):
        layer = root.findLayer(id)
        if isinstance(layer.layer(), QgsRasterLayer):
            nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(layer)
            
            # remove "Band 1 (gray)" and invert order
            if nodes[0].data(0) == 'Band 1 (Gray)':
                indexes = list(range(1, len(nodes)))
                QgsMapLayerLegendUtils.setLegendNodeOrder(layer, list(reversed(indexes)))
                model.refreshLayerLegend(layer)
```

Now I uploaded the QGIS file to the server, but the changes don't show up on QGIS Server `GetLegendGraphic` request. The change definitely does show up in the .qgs file and looks like that:

```xml
<customproperties>
    <Option type="Map">
      <Option name="legend/node-order" value="5,4,3,2,1" type="QString"/>
    </Option>
</customproperties>
```

Is `legend/node-order` something QGIS Server doesn't have in mind and I would have to create a QGIS Server plugin?

Comment: You'd better ask official user or dev mailing list to validate if this a bug or intended.

Comment: I already did ask it on [dev mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2022-December/065311.html), but didn't get any answer.